# Why the time complexity of the following c++ code is O(n^n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is the brute force solution of this lettcode problem: https://leetcode.com/articles/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/, and I don't get why the time complexity if O(n^n) as claimed. Can anyone explain and walk me through it, thanks!

```
class Solution {
    public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
        return calculate(prices, 0);
    }

    public int calculate(int prices[], int s) {
        if (s >= prices.length)
            return 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int start = s; start < prices.length; start++) {
            int maxprofit = 0;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < prices.length; i++) {
                if (prices[start] < prices[i]) {
                    int profit = calculate(prices, i + 1) + prices[i] - prices[start];
                    if (profit > maxprofit)
                        maxprofit = profit;
                }
            }
            if (maxprofit > max)
                max = maxprofit;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a recursive call in the innermost loop the expansion tree will look like below

```
                                        0
                ---------------------------------------------------------
                1                               2   ..                  n
    ------------------------            ---------------------          
    2           3  ..      n            3           4   ..  n   
----------  -------------       ----------   ------------
3   4 .. n  4   5  ..   n       4   5 .. n   5  6   ..  n
                                       ...
```

On first row there are `n-1` or `O(n)` operations, on second row there are `(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = n*(n-1)/2` or `O(n^2)` operations. Similarly on third row there are `O(n^3)` operations. The tree height/depth is `n`. So continuing this way there will be `O(n^n)` total operations.

Comment: This is great explanation, didn't realise that expansion tree should be used for analysing recursion. Thanks!