# Confusion on Time and Space Complexities On Brute Force Code

Tags: java, time-complexity, brute-force, stock, space-complexity

I recently was looking at the solutions of a problem I found on LeetCode. The problem can be seen here:
https://leetcode.com/articles/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/#

Regarding the brute force approach the article details, I do not understand why the time complexity is O(n^n). I believe it should be O(n!). I also do not understand why the space complexity is O(N) since no arrays seem to be stored.

Here is the code for the brute force solution for the problem:

```
class Solution {
    public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
        return calculate(prices, 0);
    }

    public int calculate(int prices[], int s) {
        if (s >= prices.length)
            return 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int start = s; start < prices.length; start++) {
            int maxprofit = 0;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < prices.length; i++) {
                if (prices[start] < prices[i]) {
                    int profit = calculate(prices, i + 1) + prices[i] - prices[start];
                    if (profit > maxprofit)
                        maxprofit = profit;
                }
            }
            if (maxprofit > max)
                max = maxprofit;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I believe it should be O(n!)"*, could you explain why you think that?

Comment: @akuzminykh The outer loop is like n and the inner loop is n-1. And then the outer loop becomes n-1 and the inner loop becomes n-2. And so on so forth

Comment: @D-Studios did you notice the recursive call, that is what makes it exponential

Comment: @D-Studios The formally correct proof is a little bit difficult for this case, you have to do much writing. But trust me this is *O(n^n)*. If/when I have time I'll post the proof here.

Comment: @akuzminykh My [empirical evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61316186/5221149) says otherwise, i.e. _O(2^n)_, not _O(n^n)_.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try with empirical evidence, i.e. count the cost.

Worst case is when `prices` are in increasing order, so `if (prices[start] < prices[i])` is always true.

The "cost" would be running the code inside the nested `if` statement, plus the cost of the recursive call.

So to force-count the cost, we change the method to:

```
public static int calculate(int n, int s) {
    int cost = 0;
    for (int start = s; start < n; start++) {
        for (int i = start + 1; i < n; i++) {
            cost++; // "cost" is the work we do here
            cost += calculate(n, i + 1); // which includes the recursive call
        }
    }
    return cost;
}
```

If we run with various values of `n`, we get:

```
n = 1: cost = 0, 2^n = 2, factor = 0.00
n = 2: cost = 1, 2^n = 4, factor = 0.25
n = 4: cost = 7, 2^n = 16, factor = 0.44
n = 8: cost = 127, 2^n = 256, factor = 0.50
n = 16: cost = 32767, 2^n = 65536, factor = 0.50
n = 32: cost = 2147483647, 2^n = 4294967296, factor = 0.50
```

So we can see the cost is about `2^n / 2`, which means ***O(2^n)***, not *O(n^n)*.

---

For comparison, if we remove the recursive call, i.e. comment out that line of code, we get:

```
n = 1: cost = 0, n^2 = 1, factor = 0.00
n = 2: cost = 1, n^2 = 4, factor = 0.25
n = 4: cost = 6, n^2 = 16, factor = 0.38
n = 8: cost = 28, n^2 = 64, factor = 0.44
n = 16: cost = 120, n^2 = 256, factor = 0.47
n = 32: cost = 496, n^2 = 1024, factor = 0.48
n = 64: cost = 2016, n^2 = 4096, factor = 0.49
n = 128: cost = 8128, n^2 = 16384, factor = 0.50
n = 256: cost = 32640, n^2 = 65536, factor = 0.50
n = 512: cost = 130816, n^2 = 262144, factor = 0.50
n = 1024: cost = 523776, n^2 = 1048576, factor = 0.50
```

So we can see the cost is about `n^2 / 2`, which means ***O(n^2)***, which is what we expect from a nested loop.

Comment: What about space complexity? Why is it O(N)? An array is not being stored.

Comment: @D-Studios The code has _O(n)_ space complexity because the maximum recursion depth, i.e. the maximum depth of the call stack, is linear to `n`.

Comment: How did you find out to use 2^n. It seems that was sort of guessed and checked.

Comment: @D-Studios I looked at the number sequence: 7, 127, 32767, 2147483647, ... Those are very recognizable numbers to programmers with some experience with binary numbers, so I suspected 2^n, calculated it and the factor, to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Are you sure its 2^n? This is because the solution states the time complexity is O(n^n). Furthermore, I was recently fiddling around and drew an expansion tree regarding the recursion. I realized that for like every n, a branch would result in like (n-1) or (n-2) etc. So basically for each level in the tree depth, there should be around n^of that number of that level. There seems to be n levels the expansion tree. However, even though I thought this justified the n^n, I realized there was an n^2 for each and every number in each level of the tree. Is the time greater than O(n^n)? @Andreas

Comment: @D-Studios As the answer already stated, I go by the *empirical evidence*, which shows a time complexity of _O(2^n)_, not _O(n^n)_. I haven't attempted a mathematical proof. If the time complexity had been _O(n^n)_, then the cost for `n=32` would be closer to **1e48**, not the measly **4e9** seen here. --- Actually, the code wouldn't have shown any result for `n=32`, because it would still be counting for many more years. The reason the output stopped at 32 is because higher values took too long, so I cancelled it.

Comment: I realized a similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797066/why-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-c-code-is-onn?rq=1.
The answer was also O(n^n).